# Perl regex to find and replace php multiline comments

Tags: php, javascript, regex, perl

I am trying to find a way to shrink my PHP/JavaScript code by removing all of my single and multiple line comments. Currently I have the single line removal working but I can not figure out how to make my multiple line comments remove. I have tried the following regular expressions:

```
\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/
\/\*[^.\/]*\*\/
```

And many others. The current expression I am using to find the single lines and failing the multi lines is `(\/\/[^\n]*\n|\/\*[^\*\/]*\*\/)`

### Expression Requirements

- The expression must be in Perl
- The expression must not stop at `//` inside the multiline comment (ie. http://url.com)
- The expression must be able to find both single and multiline comments
- The expression can be used to find the beginning and end of any multiline PHP/JavaScript comment.

A sample of code you can test on that I will need it for can be [found here](http://regexr.com?361c2)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: To shrink source code when pushing newer versions.

Comment: After the line containing `$(function(){`, there is `/**` which seems out of place?

Comment: Your single line regex isn't working correctly too as it will match URLs which aren't comments, and will match `//` inside string literals.

Comment: @Jerry No. It is actually correct. if you look after the socket.onclose closing brace there is a comment closer.

Comment: @Sniffer Thank you. You are correct. I will fix that later. Right now im only concerned with the multiline one.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4079920/is-there-a-point-to-minifying-php

Comment: That won't be pretty easy. As for multi-line comments @PaulS. solution should work.

Comment: @AKHolland Thank you for that link. Im not so much worried about minifying the php as I am the JS.

Comment: @Mic1780 Why not a pre-built solution such as YUI compressor?

Comment: @AKHolland Im not looking for a program to compress anything. I already have a script that pushes a new script to the user, they just are not compressed. Compressing them will be nice because it will save disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/
```

- `\/\*` match `/*`
- `[\s\S]*?` match anything (non-greedy)
- until `\*\/`; match `*/`

Comment: Why wouldn't I use `[.]*?` with dotall on? is \s\S better?

Comment: @Mic1780 what I wrote doesn't require any flags so easier to explain. Of course you can do the _dotall_ method. With _dotall_ off you can easily combine this regexp with another that matches to the end of the line, to catch `//` comments too

Answer (score 0):

http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/06/06/regexps.html

You're not going to have it work with a dot alone. That excludes the newline character.

You're going to need to use the /s option.

Answer (score 0):

There is an online [guide](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html) which gives the following perl regex.

```
(?:\/\*(?:[^*]|(?:\*+[^*\/]))*\*+\/)|(?:\/\/.*)
```

And it seems to give the correct output with your [test code](http://regexr.com?361e7).  But you might get into trouble with text like in line #10 where there are comments inside other elements.